# Strange behavior with IntentFilter resolution on a device

Tags: android, android-intent

I am experimenting with `requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent)` and a BroadcastReceiver. The code is as follows:

```
// PendingLocationDemo.java
public class PendingLocationDemo extends Activity {

    public TextView output;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        SomeReceiver receiver = new SomeReceiver(this);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("some_action");
        // filter.addAction("some_other_action");
        // filter.addAction("still_something_different");
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("some_action");
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        // Get the location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, pending);
    }

    protected void someCallback(Intent intent) {
        printObject(intent);
    }
}

// SomeReceiver.java
public class SomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    PendingLocationDemo caller;

    public SomeReceiver(PendingLocationDemo caller) {
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        caller.someCallback(intent);
    }
}
```

When I run this on a device, the output depends on the value I use for the action in the IntentFilter.

- for "some_action", the output is:
  Intent { act=some_action cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] (has extras) }
- for "some_other_action", the output is:
  Intent { act=some_other_action (has extras) }
- for "still_something_different", I do not receive the updates.

Is there a reasonable explanation for such inconsistent behavior?

Comment: Sorry the code above is a little unclear. So you register for a broadcast that will never fire (or at least I don't see where). And then you ask for a blank intent to be fired wrapped in a PendingIntent when you get a gps update? How are you getting any output? I am guessing your issue might be typo related?

Comment: You are right, the above code had a typo: the PendingIntent fires an Intent with "some_action". Then I change the action in the filter, and get either the expected output, or strange things when I don't expect any output at all.

Comment: to make it a little more clear: the first and last case are expected (actions match so I get the updates, or mismatch and no updates). The second case however is both strange and unexpected. My gut feeling is that it might be dalvik-cache related...

Comment: Are you saying that when ONLY adding the action `some_other_action` (you're not adding them all at once are you?) to your IntentFilter and broadcasting with the action `some_action` you receive updates to your receiver? If that is so you are correct in thinking it shouldn't happen. It could possibly be cache related I guess - what happens if you change `some_other_action` to `some_other_action2` or `some_other_action_A`?

Comment: @Joseph: yes, that's what I mean. This is quite an old question so I can't answer directly your question, but the point was that I tried with different values and got completely unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

This strange behaviour is due to the registration of broadcast receiver. Instead of registering the broadcast receiver you can write your code within the Location Listener which is also a broadcast receiver and listens for location updates in background.

```
final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Code for action you wish to perform on Location Changed.
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};
// ...
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            3000, locationListener);
```

Hope it helps.